# I can't connect to ServerSocket in JAVA - connection timeout

Tags: java, sockets, networking, timeout

I trying to connect between two applications in Java:

```
//server
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5052);
server.accept();

//client
Socket soc = new Socket("192.68.x.x", 5052);
```

If my computer is a client and a different computer is a server, everything works but if the server is located on my computer the other computer can not get access (Connection timeout). Why ? I switched off my firewall.

Comment: Did you also try `127.0.0.1:5052` (i.e. localhost)? BTW: private IPs start usually with `192.168....` not with `192.68....` ...

Comment: I made a mistake, in the code during testing it was well. I don't try but why one of my computer can by a server in my way and other connot ?

Comment: If you can connect to the server hosted on another server and cannot connect to the same server running locally, there are some errors possible, e.g.: (1) is the interface _up_ (_activated_ in Windows)? (2) Is the provided IP the one which is configured for the interface (check `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` for Windows) (3) could the port be blocked by another server application (check with `netstat`) (4) do you have an error in the program (debug it)